# SQL function to divide one row in four distinct rows

Tags: sql, hana

Does anyone has an idea on how to split the yearly financial revenue from a single row into 4 rows representing the four quarters? (assuming every quarter generates the same amount of revenues)? Here below an example: on the upper side what I currently have and on the lower side the splitting I want to achieve.

[image: Text]

I did some research over the internet and found `CROSS JOIN` could definitely help but don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HANA comes with specific disaggregation functions that work on **SERIES** tables/data and that can handle *horizontal disaggregation* similar to the described requirement. (see docu [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b2f4bdf7b83f4444bfab5564e9ff6aee/2.0.05/en-US/e1052c9db6f8409ca99ef4d729d0dc77.html))

However, *series data* requires some pre-thought and familiarity with the concepts, so the following is a "series light" version of a statement that solves the problem:

```
DROP TABLE geo_years;
CREATE COLUMN TABLE geo_years(
    geo_level_1 nvarchar (20)
    , geo_level_2 nvarchar (20)
    , YEAR integer
    , revenue decimal (10, 2)
);

INSERT INTO geo_years VALUES ('EUROPE', 'FRANCE', 2020, 100.00);
INSERT INTO geo_years VALUES ('EUROPE', 'FRANCE', 2021, 200.00);

SELECT 
      gy.geo_level_1
    , gy.geo_level_2
    , gy."YEAR"
    , st.GENERATED_PERIOD_START pstart
    , quarter(add_months(to_date(gy."YEAR"), 3 * (st.GENERATED_period_start-1))) AS QUATER_DATE
    , to_decimal (revenue / 4, 10, 2) AS revenue_disagg
    FROM 
        geo_years gy
    cross JOIN series_generate_integer (1, 1, 5) st
ORDER BY
    geo_level_1, geo_level_2, "YEAR", pstart;

GEO_LEVEL_1|GEO_LEVEL_2|YEAR|PSTART|QUATER_DATE|REVENUE_DISAGG|
-----------+-----------+----+------+-----------+--------------+
EUROPE     |FRANCE     |2020|     1|2020-Q1    |         25.00|
EUROPE     |FRANCE     |2020|     2|2020-Q2    |         25.00|
EUROPE     |FRANCE     |2020|     3|2020-Q3    |         25.00|
EUROPE     |FRANCE     |2020|     4|2020-Q4    |         25.00|
EUROPE     |FRANCE     |2021|     1|2021-Q1    |         50.00|
EUROPE     |FRANCE     |2021|     2|2021-Q2    |         50.00|
EUROPE     |FRANCE     |2021|     3|2021-Q3    |         50.00|
EUROPE     |FRANCE     |2021|     4|2021-Q4    |         50.00|
```

The key elements here are:

- generate 4 records for every record in the `geo_year`: this is done by `CROSS JOIN series_generate_integer (1, 1, 5) st`. See docu for this function [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.05/en-US/c8101037ad4344768db31e68e4d30eb4.html).
- calculate the begin dates for every quarter and format the result as YYYY-QTR: `quarter(add_months(to_date(gy."YEAR"), 3 * (st.GENERATED_period_start-1))) AS QUATER_DATE`
- distribute the `REVENUE` evenly over the number of quarters (4): `to_decimal (revenue / 4, 10, 2) AS revenue_disagg`

And that is really all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
select geo_level1,geo_level2,year,q.quarter,revenue / 4
from table t
join (select * from values ((1),(2),(3),(4)) q(quarter))
 on 1 = 1
```